# NSDate! How to retrieve date from the NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: swift, core-data, nsdate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a tableView with `NSFetchedResultsController`! It works well. I want to display date on my tableViewCell like many iOS apps. When I added a new item to the list and then `NSManagedObjectContext` saved it with the `NSDate` like so:

```
let entity:Manager = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Manager", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! Manager

entity.setValue(textField.text, forKey: "title") 

entity.setValue(NSDate(), forKey: "time")

do { try self.managedObjectContext.save()

} catch {

}
```

It's my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method!

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(ReuseIdentifierToDoCell, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

   if let access:Manager = self.frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? Manager {

        cell.firstLabel.text = access.valueForKey("title") as? String
        cell.secondLabel.text = access.valueForKey("time") as? NSDate
    }
```

Everything works perfectly! But I do not need default time like this:

`time = "2016-02-01 06:16:15 +0000";
    title = One;`

I need time and month only.
 Thanks for attention!

Comment: Use `NSDateFormatter`

Comment: It's ok! But I do not know, how to use

Comment: Read the documentation and https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html. It's pretty straightforward.

Comment: I need a Swift Programming Language not an Objective C! Can you help by code? How to implement it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Because I'm new to the iOS App Development! Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Thanks for your help! I found! Again thanks